Getting bounding box for scratch layer source using PyQGIS
I drew a New Temporary Scratch Layer, named New Scratch Layer, in QGIS. Both layer and project CRS are EPSG:3857. I am trying to compute its bounding box using PyQGIS. I use the following script:
[source] = [
    layer.source()
    for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()
    if "New scratch layer" in layer.name()
] # source is then: 'Polygon?crs=EPSG:3857&uid={677b10e0-f6cb-4885-85c0-52f040f0b481}'

layer = QgsVectorLayer(source, "temp_layer", "memory")

print(layer.extent())

But the output I get has huge numbers:
<QgsRectangle: 179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368 179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368, -179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368 -179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368>

Screenshot of the situation:

So I think I am doing something wrong, or I am not able to interpret these numbers correctly.
How do I compute the correct extent for a scratch layer source using PyQGIS?

Why not just layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('New scratch layer')[0] print(layer.extent())?

Good point, that works indeed, the numbers returned are actually correct.

layer.updateExtents() seems to be needed. Do:
[layer] = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('New scratch layer')
layer.updateExtents()
print(layer.extent())

Then the result will not be overly enormous.
